# Maximum length of a Groovy script run via Liferay Console

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Liferay has a web console that allows administrators to run Groovy scripts.

What are the technical limitations of this web console in terms of length of the Groovy script I can run?

For instance, if I paste a 1 million lines script into the console's text area, I guess I will start running into web protocol limitations, or limitations of Groovy itself?

Is there a rule of thumb or an official limit? Either in terms of lines of bytes or instructions or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Before reaching the place where it will be executed you will reach the POST limit set in your installation (server/liferay limit).

Comment: I can upload a big video file which is much heavier than a 1 million lines script. So I guess that should not be a problem :-)